# Not able to access GAC assembly in asp.net Web application

Tags: asp.net, gac, production

I have developed an asp.net web application using .net framework 4.0.

I have installed few dlls in GAC and have added their reference in my web application , so that I can use it. These dlls are compiled in .net framework 3.5.

After development , when I published my application and deployed in my local IIS , it is working fine.
After this testing , I have deployed same content at Test server and Stage server. and also installed those required dlls in GAC.Everything is working till now.

But when I deployed same content and followed same steps at production server, it started giving me error message "Could not load file or assembly...". This is showing that my web application is not able to access that GAC assembly.

I have tried lot to solve this issue , but not able to find any solution.

One **major difference** I found in all environment is , the OS is installed in D: at production server, while OS is installed in C: in other environment where its working fine.
This might be causing issue. if yes, then what should be the solution for this.

I don't want to put these dlls in my BIN folder, I have tested by doing this and its working fine. I have to use dlls installed in GAC only.

Please help me .

Comment: Can you use on your production box fuslogvw.exe (in the .Net/Windows sdk) with the option Log all Binds to verify that loading of the dlls is indeed from C:\ instead of D:\ like you expect.

Comment: Is the appdomain running under a system account or a domainaccount?